# Select client informations about his reservation in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'd like to isplay the name, address and phone number for the clients who has not made any reservations for the past two months.

The tables are :

```
CLIENT (
 ClientNo,
 Name,
 Sex,
 DOB,
 Address,
 Phone,
 Email,
 Occupation,
 MaritalStatus,
 Spouse,
 Anniversary
)
RESERVATION 
 ResNo,
 ResDate,
 NoOfGuests,
 StartDate,
 EndDate,
 ClientNo,
 Status
)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT Name, Address, Phone, ResNo
FROM Client C, Reservation R
WHERE Date_Column >= ResDate R(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
ORDER BY Name DESC
```

Comment: Name should be displayed in alphabetical order).

I have tried the following but it doesn't work;

SELECT Name, Address, Phone, ResNo

FROM Client C, Reservation R

WHERE Date_Column >= ResDate R(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) 

ORDER BY Name DESC;

Comment: Please do not post parts of the question as comments, edit the question instead; whar do you mean with "it doesn't work"? are you having an error? an unexpected result?

Comment: SQL> SELECT C.Name, C.Address, C.Phone, R.ResNo, R.ResDate
FROM Client C, Reservation R
WHERE ResDate R >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2)
ORDER BY Name ASC;  2    3    4
WHERE ResDate R >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2)
              *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Please do not post parts of the question as comments, edit the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an *outer* join, with all conditions in the join, and then filter out all successful joins:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM Client C
LEFT JOIN Reservation R ON C.ID = R.ID -- outer join
  AND R.ResDate >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2) -- condition in join
WHERE R.ID IS NULL -- only return missed joins
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

You want the missed joins - ones where there are no reservations at all given the conditions. Such missed joins have all-nulls in the joined table's columns, so filtering on (one of) those columns being null will return clients who don't have any such reservations.

Comment: SQL>  SELECT C.Name, C.Address, C.Phone, R.ResNo, R.ResDate
FROM Client C
LEFT JOIN Reservation R ON C.ClientNo = R.ResNo
  AND R.ResDate >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2))
WHERE R.ResNo IS NULL
ORDER BY Name ASC;  2    3    4    5    6
  AND R.ResDate >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2))
                                                    *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @TuğçeDemir there was an extra bracket in there. try edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your where condition like

```
ResDate >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2)
```

Also you are missing the JOIN for your table. So you need to put the JOIN like

```
 SELECT C.Name, C.Address, C.Phone, R.ResNo, R.ResDate
 FROM Client C INNER JOIN Reservation R ON C.ID = R.ID   --Change the column for Joing as per your table structure
 WHERE R.ResDate >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2)) 
 ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

Comment: @TuğçeDemir:- You need to put the actual name of the `date_column` for which you are comparing

Comment: I did
SQL> SELECT C.Name, C.Address, C.Phone, R.ResNo, R.ResDate
FROM Client C, Reservation R
WHERE ResDate R >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2)
ORDER BY Name ASC;  2    3    4
WHERE ResDate R >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2)
              *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: am I using the right date or is it meant to be startdate or end date?

Comment: SQL>  SELECT C.Name, C.Address, C.Phone, R.ResNo, R.ResDate
 FROM Client C INNER JOIN Reservation R ON C.ClientNo = R.ResNo
 WHERE R.ResDate >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2))
 ORDER BY Name ASC;  2    3    4
 WHERE R.ResDate >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2))
                                                     *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @TuğçeDemir:- Are you missing a semicolon `;` at last?

Comment: SQL> SELECT C.Name, C.Address, C.Phone, R.ResNo, R.ResDate FROM Client C, Reservation R WHERE ResDate R >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2) ORDER BY Name ASC;

Nope